# Instagram API comments webhook

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, webhooks

I try to integrate Instagram into my web app.
I need receive webhook by each comment in my media.

I create a Client in Instagram/developers and POST subscription,
But only receive when posting a media.

When another way, 
I try with Facebook Instagram API, and receive webhook from a commets,
but if the user which write the commets isn´t a business account, I´m can´t get a data from the user.

Any suggestion?
Existe another way to integrate API Instagram?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No. You have covered the possible scenario. Comment webhooks are only supported in the FB graph API. And to use that you need to connect with business account. They don't support comment webhooks for non-business account.